# json not deserialising to class

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am able to deserialise my hash, however cannot seem to deserialise my attribute field to my attribute class, here is my json object

```
    {
        "attribute": {
            "status": "FWD",
            "type": "P2p",
            "cost": "4",
            "role": "Desg",
            "priorityNo": "128.1"
        },
        "hash": "50f74cc4c03637b753e884c4dfbd4270089658e5"
    }
```

and here are my c# classes

```
public class InterfaceObject 
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    Attribute attribute { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string priorityNo { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to deserialise the hash in the interface object, however cannot seem to deserialise my attribute class and here is how I try to deserialise my object

```
InterfaceObject ifa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InterfaceObject>(message);
```

Comment: What are you using for serialization/deserialization?

Comment: @DVK I am using newtonsoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Comment: Please show your deserialization code.

Comment: `attribute` is a property of `Gi1/0/1`, not `iface`. But good luck creating a property by that name.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568448/deserializing-complex-object-using-json-net

Comment: @DStanley I have updated my post

Comment: Is your json like you originally showed, or like this edit?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `public` on your `attribute` property. Json.Net cannot set values to `private` properties without adding an additional attribute on the property.

```
public class InterfaceObject 
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public Attribute attribute { get; set; }
}
```

Add `public` and it will work.

Comment: FYI, Json.NET *can* deserialize non-public properties, but you have to use a `[JsonProperty]` attribute on the property to enable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your deserialization is not working properly is, as Crowcoder pointed out, `attribute` is a property of `Gi1/0/1`. You need create an all-encompassing class to contain your already made classes for this to work.

Something like this would do:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public InterfaceObject iObject { get; set; }
}

public class InterfaceObject 
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public Attribute attribute { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public string hash { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string cost { get; set; }
    public string priorityNo { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

However now that you have changed your original post, you should be able to parse it the way that you have, assuming your JSON looks like the edited version.