# Deserialize nested json in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I am using the json.net library and I have this json file I want to deserialize:

```
  {
   "location":"/UndefinedTag/UndefinedPos/1480679543072",
   "parameters":{
      "SwitchPoint1":{
         "SamplingRate":null,
         "BitLength":16,
         "BitOffset":0,
         "DataType":"BooleanT"
      },
      "SwitchPoint2":{
         "SamplingRate":null,
         "BitLength":16,
         "BitOffset":1,
         "DataType":"BooleanT"
      },
      "SensorValue":{
         "SamplingRate":null,
         "BitLength":14,
         "BitOffset":2,
         "DataType":"IntegerT"
      }
   }
}
```

can anybody help ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Deserializing complex object using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568448/deserializing-complex-object-using-json-net) first (altough it's C#-related). In your case you need several .NET object types defined beforehand:

- "parent" one holding `location` and `parameters` properties (where `parameters` represents collection of "named sensors")
- "named sensor" representing each specialized sensor type, such as `SwitchPoint1`, `SwitchPoint2` or `SensorValue` (where each "named sensor" type contains related "sensor value" property)
- "sensor value" holding single sensor properties such as `SamplingRate`, `BitLength`, etc.